# Setting a stoploss at the entry candle's high in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

The stop placement for a script I'm working on should be one pip above the signal candle's high.

Simple question... But I can't seem to find anything that can do it in the reference

Comment: Have you had a look here?
"https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy{dot}exit" (plase copy the whole URL and paste it in your browser as link is ignoring the {dot}exit part)

Comment: Yes the reference that I talk about in my question is this... I can't find out how to set a stop at the trigger candle high though.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? You don't have to share all your always-winning strategy, though :) Just anything that would show what you have tried, and where to start from to help you out.